# Where did Tobi get his left eye from?

Tags: naruto

Thinking back about Tobi's battle with Konan, he used Izanagi to escape from Konan's ultimate technique!
I searched through blogs and Narutopedia but couldn't get the source of his left eye, that he used to overcome Konan's ultimate technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is not explicitly stated as such, he supposedly gathered several Sharingans during the Uchiha incident.

This "cupboard" in the room where he operated on Sasuke is probably where he preserves his "collection". He has been showed standing next to it on one or two other occasions.

[image: Tobi with his "collection"]

Comment: Was he the one accompanied itachi in 'uchiha pursuit'

Comment: if yes then it is very much clarified ..

Comment: It is known that Itachi knew Tobi and his grudge for the Uchiha clan before he did the massacre. Also, it was essentially Danzo who ordered Itachi to massacre the clan. When Tobi meets Danzo during the Five Kage meeting, he remarks that they had not met since the Uchiha incident, which implies that Tobi was also somehow involved with it. We later learned that Danzo gathered 10 Sharingans during that massacre, so Tobi probably took the rest.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

So here we have to look at Tobi's left eye. The one he used for izagani. I researched a bit into it and looked into Sharingan user eyes since it struck me as very familiar. I realized Madara's EMS looked very similar to it, and I decided to look up his brother's eyes since EMS is a combination. The bottom picture of the Sharingan eye is Madara's brother, Izuna Uchiha, eye. Taken that Madara saved Obito/Tobi, I believe that when Madara died, he took his eyes. However this is a theory, but the eyes are very similar.

Comment: You'd do a bit better with more evidence than just a picture.  There's nothing to suggest that this isn't an error in how the manga itself was drawn, and I don't think that this particular scene when animated indicated this specific tomoe pattern.